# Confused - objects calling methods calling methods

Tags: php

I often see code like this:

```
X::y()->z();
```

Is this a static object calling a method y, the result of y returning an object, and this object then calling a method called z?

Thank you.

Comment: correct. Or do you have any counter-idea?

Comment: Pretty much "yes", if you replace static object with static class

Comment: or rather than "static object calling a method y", say "call a static method y of the class X"

Comment: Search "Singleton pattern in PHP". Real world example would be `db::instance()->query('SELECT * FROM EMP')`

Comment: @Atif - could just as easily be an object factory

Answer (score 1):

The static object is not calling `y`, but the method `y` is called on a class, statically. Aside from that, you're correct.

Comment: that's not 100% correct. There is no proof that *X* is static. You can only say that *y* is static.

Comment: Right! X wouldn't be static

Answer (score 0):

It could look like this:

```
class X {
  public static function y(){
    return new self();
  }

  public function z(){

  }
}
```

Comment: *y()* could return anything

Comment: @Lame-up-duck Thanks, I didnt know about that. That was just the shortest example.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment seemed as a cpt. Obvious cite :). I think your answer is correct but not for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a static method *y()* on an object *X* and then you are calling *z()* method on the resulting object returned from *y()*

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be a static method call. If the call is made from inside an instantiated class and `X` is a parent of that class, then that call **may** be non-static.

One thing is for sure: `X::y()` returns an object.